# How can I get value from above row with same ID if row is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new with SQL and I encountered this.
[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVOEK.png)

My question is how can I make all the `NULL` on `primary_payer_id` get the value above only if they have same ClientID and ActionCode `IS NOT NULL`. FYI CustomColumn is only a copy of primary_payer_id ALSO I attached my code here below.

Here's my code:

```
       SELECT ci.client_id AS ClientID,
               ci.primary_payer_id,                         
               ci.effective_date AS EffectiveDate,
               ci.action_code_id AS ActionCode,
               cc.item_description AS ItemDesc,
               ap.description AS IDescription,
               ci.deleted 



        FROM census_item ci

            LEFT JOIN common_code cc ON ci.adt_tofrom_id = cc.item_id
            LEFT JOIN ar_lib_payers ap ON ci.primary_payer_id = ap.payer_id 

        WHERE ci.deleted = 'N'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more efficient method, but this will work:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*,
       (case when t.actioncode is not null and t.clientid is null
             then tprev.clientid
             else t.clientid
        end) as new_clientid
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.clientid = t.clientid and
            tprev.effectivedate < t.effectivedate
      order by tprev.effecctivedate desc
     ) tprev;
```

Comment: Thank You. I should have posted my actual codes. But it did help though. Thank You again